# find() in created function system.js mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use find() but in function system.js in mongo db but when i run the script the result is [image]

this is my findstored() function

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id:"findstored", 
    value:function(){ 
        var data = db.counters.find({}, (err, data) => {
            data.forEach((data) => {
               print("Customer Name: "+data.first_name)
            })
            return data.first_name;
       })
    }
})
```

I just want to display the result with function in system.js. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is the purpose of your function, but this is the right syntax for that function to be saved in `system.js`:

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id:"findstored", 
    value:function(){
        var ret = "Not found";
        db.counters.find().forEach(function(data){
                print("Customer Name: "+data.first_name)
                ret = data.first_name;
                })
                return ret;
                }
    })
```

And make sure you run `db.loadServerScripts();` after saving the function to have it properly loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Do not store application logic in the database. There are performance limitations to running JavaScript inside of MongoDB.

```
    db.system.js.save({
      _id:"findUserInformation", 
      value:function(x){ 
        return db.users.findOne({ "_id" : x }, { firstName:1 }, (err, data) => {
                return data
        })
      }
   })
```

On other shell or command use this findUserInformation function like this

```
db.loadServerScripts();
findUserInformation("5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cb");
```

In your question please check return type and run query first and then return data. 
In findstored function Application code also is typically most effective when it shares version control with the application itself.